# Error response in Django

Tags: django, curl, error-handling, httpresponse

A client wants to upload a file with the `curl` command, and I need to validate its data.

What kind of response should I give to indicate that the file is corrupted, so that the client can use the exit code of `curl` to figure out whether or not it succeeded?
(i.e. I don't want to make him parse HTML.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP code 400 is `Bad Request`, which is probably the best bet here.

No reason for HTML, though. The response can be simply plain text, or something like JSON.